# porque no se reconoce la variable que esta contenida en otro archivo?

Tags: php, php7

mi script esta jerarquizado de la siguiente manera:

```
public
-- index.php
--/inc
----- conx.php
----- funciones.php
```

estoy llamando desde el index la función

> calc_IPGJO($equipo);

que esta en el archivo funciones.php quien a su misma vez llama al archivo conx.php mediante un

> include_once('conx.php');

```
function calc_IPGJO($equipo){
        $remates = 0;
        $goles = 0;
        $pases = 0;
        
        $resultado = [];
            
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM dbf WHERE HomeTeam='.$equipo.'OR AwayTeam='.$equipo.'Order by Date desc LIMIT 5';
        foreach($conexion->query($sql) as $row){
            
            if($row['HomeTeam'] == $equipo){
                $remates = $row['HS'];
                $goles = $row['FTHG'];
                $pases = $row['HPAS'];
            }else{
                $remates = $row['AS'];
                $goles = $row['FTAG'];
                $pases = $row['APAS'];
            }
            $calc = (($remates+$goles)/$pase)*100;
            $resultado[$calc];
        }
        return $resultado;
    }
```

el archivo conx.php realiza la siguiente conexión a la db mediante pdo

```
try{
        $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        //echo "Connected to $dbname at $host successfully.";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $e->getMessage());
    }
```

el problema que tengo es que recibo el siguiente error:

> Undefined variable: conexion in /htdocs/inc/funciones.php on line 31

y no se ejecuta la consulta, como podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

me auto respondo :)

la variables toman un ámbito dentro del archivo pero no dentro de la función, por lo cual hay que declararlas como globales

```
global $conexion;
```

por otro lado la consulta tiene un mal escapado de las ""''

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dgf WHERE HomeTeam='".$equipo."' OR AwayTeam='".$equipo."' Order by Date desc LIMIT 5";
```